# Jekyll Sorting Accentuated Characters

Tags: jekyll

I'm failing to sort posts titles containing accentuated characters.

Using:

```
{% assign sorted_posts = (site.posts | sort: 'title') %}
```

***I get:***

- Aujourd'hui Dimanche
- Bientôt la nuit
- À vendre

**What I would like is getting:**

- Aujourd'hui Dimanche
- À vendre
- Bientôt la nuit

**In other word, make as if 'A' was equal to 'À'.**

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only solution is to make a [generator plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) that use `I18n.transliterate` to transform accented characters from title and create something like a `slug` field for each post.

Posts will then be sortable by slug.